# Rails Globalize3 gem: How do I add an additional field to the translation table using a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalization

The docs for the Globalize3 gem are clear about how to create a translation table, but I don't see any information about how to add a field to a translation table during a later migration. For example, I initially included `Category.create_translation_table! :name => :string` when I created my Category model. Now, however, I need to add a translated field to the model.

How do I do that with a Rails migration? I don't see any docs for an `alter_translation_table!` method or anything similar...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Globalize4, just :

```
class AddHintToCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Category.add_translation_fields! hint: :text
  end

  def down
    remove_column :category_translations, :hint
  end
end
```

Don't forget to add the new field in your model :

```
translate :name, :hint
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it by hand, something like the following:

```
class AddNewFieldToYourTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:your_tables) do |t|
      t.string :new_field
    end
    change_table(:your_table_translations) do |t|
      t.string :new_field
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :your_tables, :new_field
    remove_column :your_table_translations, :new_field
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll give this a try when I get the chance. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Clay I think this solution doesn't work, I tried it and it gave me strange errors. First I had to remove the translation line in the model for the added attribute to do a `rake db:migrate`, then I couldn't update the entity. I took the freedom to add an issue to the globalize3 issuetracker https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/issues/98

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just don't forget to add the column in the translates line in the model.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/master/lib/globalize/active_record/migration.rb:34 line (globalize 4)

```
add_translation_fields!(fields, options)
```

P.S. Just a typo in a previous comment, 'add_transaction_fields' isn't defined.